# How to create and simulate fictive time for a business simulation game

Tags: c#, game-engine, simulation

I am total beginner in C#, except that I went through the Microsoft courses and finished some basic projects. Now I thought to try something on my own, creating a very basic business simulation game with a c# form in Visual Studio.

I asked Google but had a hard time to find what I am looking for. I do basically want to start off with a system that simulates days. Let's say I have a button that I can press to play forward, and when I do this, a pre-defined date like 1 January 2017 should increase with +1 day ticks as long as I don't click on that button again to pause the game. This is for example how it works in the game Europa Universalis IV, except that I can even increase the speed by 5 levels in that game, but this would be a bit too much now.

I just want to understand how the basic concept of a simulated date in economy based, or strategy based games is working. I featured out that they do even use 28 days in February in Europa Universalis IV... so, how is the time or date game logic working. I'd like to create this system too to understand it. I guess I need a form project, 1 button, 1 timer and 1 label.

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: This is far too broad and off topic for SO.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: For a total beginner, this seems like quite a big task to tackle. You're mostly on the right track - what you're missing would be an 'Update' method. Lets say every time you call Update, you advance the date a day. So the implementation would be on the lines of `_currentDate = _currentDate.AddDays(1)`. Then you hookup the timer to call said method, and have your button alter the how fast the timer calls `Update`. That said, this question is really too broad for Stack overflow - this site is defined for very specific questions

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things.
You need a timer to drive this.
You probably want to run increments smaller than 1 day, say 1 hour
This is a VERY rough outline

1. On button click, timer.Enabled = !timer.Enabled (this reverses the timer state, you probably want to update UI and such as well)
2. In the timer_Elapsed event, you want to update your game state (e.g. _now = _now.AddHours(1); UpdateState(); UpdateUI();)

Comment: There are several timers you can choose from.  Which you use will depend largely on your front end technology.